# Laravel Controller: How is the best way to arrange blocks of codes for this purpose

Tags: php, laravel, oop, controller

In the block of quote below i intent to achieve 5 things

1. Receive input from form
2. Check if user has enough balance hence the IF statement
3. Insert transaction record into DB
4. Update Status in the Invoices table
5. Update Status Vehicles table

   public function store1(Request $request, $invoice_id)
       {

   ```
        $invoice = Invoice::find($invoice_id);
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->added_on = Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $transaction->pay_ref = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
        $transaction->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
        $transaction->paid_amount = $request->paid_amount;
        $transaction->paid_method = 'Wallet';
        $transaction->status = 1;
        $transaction->invoice()->associate($invoice);
        $transaction->save();


        $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());


        if (Auth::user()->amount<$transaction->paid_amount){
           $user->amount = Auth::user()->amount - $transaction->paid_amount;
           $user->update();

        }else{
           Flash::error('insufficient Balance');
           return redirect(route('transactions.index'));

        }

         $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($invoice_id);
        $invoice->status = 1;
        $invoice->update();

        $vehicle = Vehicle::findOrFail($invoice_id);
        $vehicle->status = 2;
        $vehicle->update();

        Flash::success('Transaction done successfully.');
        return redirect(route('transactions.index'));
   ```

   }

   }

So far the code has been able to do 1, 3, and 4.

I have rearranged the codes severally to achieve the results but i cant get the balance checking to work and even with insufficient funds, it gives negative balance.

I cant seem to get the Vehicle status to update too cos if i try with this

```
   $vehicle = Vehicle::findOrFail($transaction_id);
             $vehicle->status = 2;
             $vehicle->update();
```

I get "undefined variable: transaction_id"
And when i try with invoice_id it runs but updates only invoice table and does not update Vehicles.

If anyone can show me how to rearrange the codes to achieve my goal, I am waiting . If you can also point out to me why my vehicle table is not be update, it will be good.

Comment: looks to me that you're trying to find the vehicle by the $invoice_id. shouldn't you use $vehicle_id instead?

Something like this... `$vehicle = Vehicle::findOrFail($vehicle_id);`

Or if you want the find the vehicle by the $transaction_id, your query should look more like this: `Vehicle::where('transaction_id', $transaction_id)->first();` assuming that you have defined a relationship between vehicles and transactions

Comment: I think something is wrong with my Transaction controller. Even the edit button on the index is giving me error of undefined variable for transaction_id. Maybe i have to sort that out before your solution can work. Thanks all the same for your contribution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following: 
1. checked the condition of IF statement and removed the else statement, 
2. You are actually trying to get the value of vehicle with invoice_id if you want to get vehicle based on invoice_id and there is invoice_id column then you'll use **where()**

```
public function store1(Request $request, $invoice_id) {

         $invoice = Invoice::find($invoice_id);

         if (Auth::user()->amount < $request->paid_amount){
            Flash::error('insufficient Balance');
            return redirect(route('transactions.index'));     
         }

         $transaction = new Transaction();
         $transaction->added_on = Carbon\Carbon::now();
         $transaction->pay_ref = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
         $transaction->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
         $transaction->paid_amount = $request->paid_amount;
         $transaction->paid_method = 'Wallet';
         $transaction->status = 1;
         $transaction->invoice()->associate($invoice);
         $transaction->save();


         $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());


          $user->amount = Auth::user()->amount - $transaction->paid_amount;
          $user->update();
          $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($invoice_id);
          $invoice->status = 1;
          $invoice->update();

         //$vehicle = Vehicle::findOrFail($invoice_id);
         //$vehicle->status = 2;
         //$vehicle->update();
         //You are actually trying to get the value of vehicle with invoice_id if you want 
         //to get vehicle based on invoice id the it will be:

         $vehicle = Vehicle::where('invoice_id',$invoice_id)->first();
         $vehicle->status = 2;
         $vehicle->update();


         Flash::success('Transaction done successfully.');
         return redirect(route('transactions.index'));   
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Doro. The balance check is now working. But i was thinking if there is a way to do the balance check before the transaction is inserted cos the way it is now even when insufficient balance is printed, transaction is added and the user is not debited,